# compareTo on int types

Tags: java

I'm trying to compare a studentNumber with each other. but I cant figuur out how to do that with 2 int types. So when you add a student to your website you can't add the student with the same studentNbr.

I tried to make it into a string but that didn't help.

```
public int compareTo(Student o) {
    if (!(this.getStudentNbr() == (o.getStudentNbr()))) {
        return this.getStudentNbr().compareToIgnoreCase(o.getStudentNbr());
        }
    if (!this.getLastName().equals(o.getLastName())) {
        return this.getLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(o.getLastName());
    }
    if (!this.getFirstName().equals(o.getFirstName())) {
        return this.getFirstName().compareToIgnoreCase(o.getFirstName());
    }

    if (o.getInsertion() != null && this.getInsertion() != null) {
        if (!this.getInsertion().equals(o.getInsertion())) {
            return this.getInsertion().compareToIgnoreCase(o.getInsertion());
        }

    } else if (this.getInsertion() == null && o.getInsertion() != null) {
        if (!getInsertion().equals(o.getInsertion())) {
            return getInsertion().compareToIgnoreCase(o.getInsertion());
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I try this code you can just add students with the same studentNbr, and thats not good.

Have someone any idea how I can compare on two int types?

Comment: `Integer.valueOf(1).compareTo(2);`

Comment: @fantaghirocco No, use `Integer.compare(1, 2)`

Comment: If `getStudentNbr()` returns an `int`, why are you trying to call `compareToIgnoreCase` on it? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Andreas was my 1st try in my IDE but completion did not popup compare after Integer. … i remebered well! :D

Comment: @Andreas uhm… *The method compareTo(Integer) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)*  :-\

Comment: @fantaghirocco I said [`Integer.compare(x, y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-), not [`x.compareTo(y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compareTo-java.lang.Integer-). It was added in Java 7, so if you don't see it, you're using an old(!) version of Java.

Answer (score 1):

You could use methods like `Integer.compare(x, y)` to compare values return if `res` is not equal to `0`:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

    private int studentNbr;
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    //...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student student) {
        int res = Integer.compare(studentNbr, student.studentNbr);
        res = res == 0 ? lastName.compareToIgnoreCase(student.lastName) : res;
        res = res == 0 ? firstName.compareToIgnoreCase(student.firstName) : res;
        // ...

        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well Answered m8

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't exactly get your code, because if you just want to compare two students based on their studentNbr, just do

```
public int compareTo(Student o) {
    Integer.compare(getStudentNbr(), o.getStudentNbr());
}
```